# SSIS Excel to CSV - 64 bit True

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012

I'm trying to convert excel(xlsx) file to CSV file - SSIS without changing 64 bit option.

All other packages run on 64 bit - True except this.

I have created a script task which doesn't work unless I turn 64 bit to False.

Used Excel source to Flat file destination works with 64 bit false but flipping back to 64 bit = true, things doesn't work anymore.

Is there a way to work with Excel and 64 bit = True in SSIS.

Need advice, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to download and install the [AccessDatabaseEngine](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) 64bit

When searching on this issue i found these articles

- http://www.madeiradata.com/load-data-excel-ssis-32-bit-vs-64-bit/
- http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.com/2009/10/quick-reference-ssis-in-32-and-64-bits.html

They contains the full story :)